# How to safely connect a gas insert to flexible steel?

Tags: gas, fireplace, heater, natural-gas

With the cold weather coming, we'd like to install a gas insert that we bought a while ago. The gas outlet that's in the fireplace in shown in the picture below.

To replace this part would require disassembling the fireplace, opening up the wall, removing the baseboard and making an access whole in a recently installed hardwood floor.

Is there another safe way to make a connection the this hose?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another safe way to make a connection the this hose?

NO there is not a SAFE way to use the damaged line in your photo.

A gas supply line has fittings pressed onto to it that are engineered for Flammable, *dangerous*, gas under pressure.

You need a new supply line.

> To replace this part would require disassembling the fireplace,
> opening up the wall, removing the baseboard and making an access whole
> in a recently installed hardwood floor.

**WHY?** There has to be access to the other end where the the line is connected to a shut off valve, NO?

Comment: There's a key-through-the-floor access to the shut off valve. No access of any other kind.

Comment: @Wynne - It difficult to believe that access to the other end of the line is not somehow provided in case the line needs to be replaced.